# How do I use the Rust crate 'boolean_expression' to implement a simple logic circuit?

Tags: rust

I would like to use the Rust crate 'boolean_expression' to implement a simple digital logic circuit. For example, suppose we have a simple circuit consisting of two 2-input logic gates, a total of three binary input signals, A, B, and C, and one binary output signal, E.

Let a first gate be a 2-input AND gate having input signals A and B and an output signal D. Let a second gate be a 2-input OR gate having inputs C and D and output E.

```
Circuit input signals: A, B, C
Circuit output signal: E

Logic gate equations:
D = A && B
E = C || D
where '&&' is the Boolean 'AND' and '||' is the Boolean 'OR'
```

Let us further suppose that we wish to implement a model of this circuit using reduced ordered binary decision diagrams (BDDs). In one common (Python, for example) implementation of a BDD package I'd define A, B, and C as Boolean variables with some sort of command such as 'let A = BDD.var' or something of that sort. I'd write the gate equations shown above as Boolean expressions. I'd apply some fixed Boolean values (True, False, possibly Don't_Care) to inputs A, B, C, or I'd simply ask "What combinations of the inputs A, B, and C define the output E?"

Now, my question is, using the teachings of the Rust crate 'boolean_expression', how do I do that? How do I define input A as a Boolean variable? How do I define my two gates? How do I examine the output signal E to determine what combinations of the inputs A, B, and C define the output E? In short, what do I type--specifically--to use the features of the Rust crate 'boolean_expression'? If you can show me what to type--all of it--I can take it from there. Thank you.

And, of course, the actual circuit I plan to implement is far more complex than this simple example.

Comment: I voted to close this question because, like [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095896/are-there-any-available-examples-of-the-use-of-the-crate-boolean-expression-in), it contains a lot of questions, which makes it hard to answer. It's basically a request for a tutorial, which is off-topic for SO, and it doesn't demonstrate research that would help an answerer know what you were having trouble with (I don't mean that you *did no research*, only that the question doesn't *show* what research you did).

Comment: Since nobody linked you to it before, the [help/on-topic] and [ask] contain a lot of helpful advice that will prevent future questions from being closed. Some questions just aren't a good fit for SO; that doesn't mean they're bad questions, but they just don't fit well in the Q&A format. We'll see if enough other people agree with me that this one should be closed, but anyway, I hope this helps you find the answers you need in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The author of Rust crate "boolean_expression" has provided the following answer as a 'main.rs' file.

```
// Add this line to dependencies:  boolean_expression = "0.3.9"
// for example, add the line under dependencies in Cargo.toml


use boolean_expression::*;

fn main() {
    let mut bdd = BDD::new();

    // Build the circuit. The arguments passed to 'bdd.terminal()'
    // can be any type, as long as they are all the same type (the 
    // 'BDD' type is polymorphic on its labels); here, we use strings.
    let a = bdd.terminal("A");
    let b = bdd.terminal("B");
    let c = bdd.terminal("C");
    let d = bdd.and(a, b);
    let e = bdd.or(c, d);

    // Can 'e' be true at all? It should be.
    assert!(bdd.sat(e));

    // Print the expression equivalent of 'e'.
    println!("e = {:?}", bdd.to_expr(e));

    // Determine a satisfying assignment of [a, b, c] to let `e` be TRUE.
    // `sat` is an Option<HashMap<T, bool>>:
    //   - if `None`, then there is no satisfying assignment.
    //       (We already checked for this case above.)
    //   - if `Some(hashmap)`, then the hashmap gives a mapping from
    //       values of type T (here, the strings we used above) to
    //       boolean values.
    let sat = bdd.sat_one(e);
    match sat {
        None => panic!("Shouldn't happen!"),
        Some(vars) => {
            for (var, value) in &vars {
                println!("Satisfying assignment: var {} = {}", var, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use the boolean_expression function bdd.from_expr().

```
let f = bdd.to_expr(e);     // create a usable expression
let g = bdd.from_expr(&f);  // include the '&' borrow symbol

println!("f is {:?}", f);   // print the expression
```

where e is a bdd, f is an expression that is printable, and g is a bdd.